# R - makeCluster hangs on localhost in Linux

Tags: linux, r, parallel-processing, localhost, cluster-computing

As the title says, `makeCluster` and `makeSOCKcluster` from the `snow` package hang when running on a linux machine..

```
cl <- makeCluster(4, type="SOCK)
cl <- makeSOCKcluster(c("localhost","localhost","localhost","localhost"))
```

Both hang and never create the workers.. This code works on my Windows 8.1 Machine (64-bit) with the same R/RStudio versions. This leads me to believe it's a configuration error. Maybe firewall? Are localhost workers affected by firewall? I've tried disabling it via `sudo ufw disable`, but the code still hangs..

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Ubuntu Linux 13.04, Raring Ringtail
RStudio Version 0.98.490
R version 3.02 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
snow_0.3-13

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering my own question..

For anyone else in this situation (many threads online but none regarding `snow`), the reason it didn't work was because it didn't have enough memory to allocate.. I cleared my workspace and lo and behold, creating clusters were instant. My guess is that `makeCluster` was waiting for resources, but they were never given up by RStudio.

Thanks.

Comment: How do you know it couldn't allocate memory? Did you get an error message?

Comment: No I came to this conclusion after many tests. It was always hanging and `top` showed 99%+ memory usage. After clearing my work space, the memory % went down to 30% and `makeCluster` worked flawlessly!